# Tensorflow Keras model: how to get the best score from a history object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train multiple machine learning models using tensorflow keras, I was just wondering is there a way to obtain the best score achieved while training after training is complete. I found online that the .fit function returns a history object which can be accessed to get the best score, though from code i've tried it says "AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'best_score'", I cannot find an attribute list online so this is why I am asking here.

Thanks in advance.

```
History = model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=1, validation_data=(Xtest, ytest), verbose=1)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (History.best_score, History.best_params_))
```

PS, I know training for 1 epoch will achieve nothing, I'm just trying to test the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want the best score from the history object.

```
hist = model.fit(...)

print(hist.history) # this will print a dictionary object, now you need to grab the metrics / score you're looking for

# if your score == 'acc', if not replace 'acc' with your metric

best_score = max(hist.history['acc'])

print(best_score)
```

If your metric is 'accuracy', use that instead.

If you want the best model, you can just use ModelCheckPoint https://keras.io/callbacks/

Comment: I'm using your method to display the best accuracy score though I am running into a new error, its a keyword error for 'acc', I am using the following code, I am also using the accuracy metric.                                                                                                               ```History = model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=2, validation_data=(Xtest, ytest), verbose=1)
    best = max(History.history['acc'])
    print(best)```

Comment: give me the output of `print(History.history)`

Comment: the output was _{'loss': [5.3577852521623885, 8.74982340676444], 'accuracy': [0.51428574, 0.45714286], 'val_loss': [7.521775245666504, 7.521775245666504], 'val_accuracy': [0.53333336, 0.53333336]}_  Ive changed 'acc' to 'accuracy' and its worked so it was just an error with accessing the correct values in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

The fit() method on keras return a history object. The history.history attribute is a dictionary recording training loss values and metrics values at successive epochs, as well as validation loss values and validation metrics values (if applicable). You can call "history.history['loss']" or "history.history['val_loss']" to access it. Here is an example of it.

```
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer =optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])
History = model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=1, validation_data=(Xtest, ytest), verbose=1)
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
```

For the best params, I think using callbacks.ModelCheckpoint might be helpful. This method has an argument  'save_best_only' to  the latest best model.

```
keras.callbacks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
```

Kindly refer to the [Training history visualization](https://keras.io/visualization/) and [callback](https://www.google.com.hk/search?hl=zh-CN&q=callbacks%2EModelCheckpoint) for more information.